# WPF MVVM - DataGrid does not update changes back to database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that is bound to a ObservableCollection that is in my NinjaList ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<NinjaVM> Ninjas { get; set; }
```

And the method where Ninjas is defined

```
public NinjaListVM()
        {
            using (var context = new NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities())
            {
                var ninjas = context.ninjas.ToList();
                Ninjas = new ObservableCollection<NinjaVM>(ninjas.Select(r => new NinjaVM(r)));
            }
        }
```

The code in my View is as followed

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2.Views"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2.ViewModel" xmlns:NinjaApp_V2="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2" x:Name="NinjaCRUDWindow" x:Class="NinjaApp_V2.Views.NinjaCRUD"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NinjaCRUD" Height="300" Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding Ninjas, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Loaded="onLoad">


    <Grid Margin="0,10,3.6,0.4">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridNinjas" ItemsSource="{Binding Ninjas, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Ninjas, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewNinja" Command="{Binding ShowNewNinja}"  Margin="10,228,103.4,-0.4" Content="New Ninja"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view does show all the contents of the Ninja table into the Grid. Also when changes are made they persist throughout the time that the application is running. But changes are not being saved to the database. My understanding is that if you bind to a ObservableCollection like this using Mode = TwoWay that it should automatically update the changes back to the database. But clearly I am missing something, can somebody perhaps point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using MvvM Light as MvvM framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the reason is that your Viewmodels haven't a direct access to the Database.

```
        //opening the database
        using (var context = new NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities()) 
        {
           //query the database and store the result in memory
            var ninjas = context.ninjas.ToList();

           //Viewmodel mapping
            Ninjas = new ObservableCollection<NinjaVM>(ninjas.Select(r => new NinjaVM(r)));
        } // in the end of the using statement the database will be "closed"
```

Manipulating an ninja doesn't affect the database.

I suspect you are using the entity framework.

so if you want to store the changes, you must reopen the Database, search for the specific ninja and overwrite the property and use the SaveChanges Methode.

For practicing you can do this in the setter

```
    public class NinjaVM
{

    private int _id;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        { 
            using (var context = new NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities())
            {
                var ninja = context.ninjas.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == _id  ));
                if(ninja == null)
                return;
                ninja.Name = value;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably going to get people saying "Strahbehry can you please not use comments on an answer to declare you forever undying love for a person" but thanks so much I've been stuck on this for multiple days and was running towards a deadline. This works and you're amazing.

Comment: as a follow up, if I delete a row now the application crashes. Do you have any idea why? It did not before.

Comment: which exception appears? i think you the first method throw the exception because they can't found the row.

Comment: This is *really* not the way to do these things - Commands are meant for such functionality. You're breaking the most basic rule of properties: do not do any function calls or anything that takes time in them.

Comment: @Maverik You are right,but I wrote for practicing he can set it in the setter, i don't think he know what an command is and how it works.... so feel free to edit my answer and implement an ICommand instead down voting my post because i want to help him

Comment: I'm not sure why I'd implement ICommand in an edit instead of posting my own answer if I intended to do that. In any case, this is a disservice to people starting WPF. A comment saying you should do it via commands and you can read about it "here" (linking somewhere) is much more helpful to person and community in general than helping them with their crutches and get even more set in bad practices. Downvote stays I'm afraid. It's of course meant to reflect disagreement which I do with this answer :)

Comment: Also: OP *is* using an ICommand already (as evident from his button Command binding) and your answer actually removed command from equation which is even worse than just not telling OP to use commands.